# Expo + React Native version mismatch error ( JavaScript version: 0.55.4, Native version: 0.57.1 )

Tags: react-native, expo

I found lots of threads about this problem, but non of them helped me out.
So sorry for writing another thread for the same problem.

I am new to react-native and frankly packange.json is really painful for me to match version of dependencies.

My package.json file is as follows.
And, error message is

```
console.error: "React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.55.4
Native version: 0.57.1
....."
```

I tried delete cache and node_modules and reinstall those things using following command.

```
"watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf node_modules/&& npm install"
```

What I found from googling, in most cases, it was version mismatch between expo and react-native. But I believe I am using matched version of react-native and expo from expo website [Here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-30-0-0-is-now-available-e64d8b1db2a7)

```
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "expo": "^30.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: hey @harry. Did you find a way to fix this? I'm getting the same error. Using react native 0.57 and expo 32.0.0. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Luciano I resolved the problem through matching sdkVersion according to MJK's answer. Could you upload the "dependencies" part of your app.json?

Comment: `app.json`:
`"react-native": "0.57.1", "expo": { "sdkVersion": "31.0.0"}, "react": "16.5.0"`
`package.json dependecies`: 
`"react": "16.5.0", "react-native": "0.57.1", "expo": "^31.0.0"`

Comment: @Luciano Krebs thanx you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is better to check app.json file as well.
sdkVersion in app.json should be matched to your version.

Answer (score 2):

run `expo update`. this will update all the dependencies in package .json to their latest most stable releases. this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just check your package.json.
Your version of 'expo' and 'react-native' must match, and remove node_modules and package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Expo**,try to run `expo update` in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

If using **Expo CLI**  - try to run `expo upgrade` to upgrade the project packages and config (check that you do have the matching versions in package.json first)